# Add values from table cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with digit values it its cells.

My objective is that by clicking on table cells and getting their values but adding them up as I click at will. It should keep track of the sum and show it in a separate `div`.

I have written code which handles clicking the `td` and adds a class which, among other things, changes the background color, necessary so that the user can see what he has clicked so far. Because classes are being added on the fly, I use `live()`.

Then I want to check on the fly the `td` that have the new class (called `selecting`) and add them up.

This is the code I have so far, but, first it does not add them up, rather, appends one after the other, and also in some weird order:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    total = '';

    $('td').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selecting');
        $('.selecting').live( {
            click: function() {
                if ($('td').hasClass('selecting')) {
                    total += $(this).html();
                }
            }
        })
        $('#feedback').text(total);
    });
})
```

A subsquent step would be that, on clicking again the `td` that were clicked, the sum is substracted for the value of the clicked again cell. So if newly clicked, adds, if clicked again, substracts, but that is like a second step, too difficult for me to do all at once first.

Comment: Also, don't use `live`. A quote from live's documentation: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().". See http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Another side note: use `var` when declaring variables. If you don't, your variable implicitly becomes global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var total = 0;
    $td.toggleClass('selecting');

    $(".selecting").each(function() {
       total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    });

    $('#feedback span').text(total);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QE3sE/)

You'll see in the code that for each click it completely re-calculates the total, this negates the need to store the total between clicks so that you can subtract the clicked value. It makes the logic a lot simpler.

Also I've removed `live()` firstly because `live()` is now deprecated and should not be used, and secondly because you don't need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
total += +$(this).text();
```

When adding a string to another string, you're *concatenating*. If you want to *addition*, you need to work with numbers. The `+` changes a string to a number.

Also, change `total = '';` for `total = 0;`.

Comment: thank you, that solves one important thing, I just did not know how to put it into numbers. I would give you very gladly useful comment but I don't even have a reputation of 15 points so they dont let me.